# EAGLE: Just Routing and Drilling

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, routing

I am trying to find the simplest way to mill this PCB with an Othermill:

[Image 1](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FXL/B88N/HOHYNN14/FXLB88NHOHYNN14.pdf)

[Image 2](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FT1/UWND/HOHYHG2F/FT1UWNDHOHYHG2F.pdf)

I currently have both images saved in the R13 DXF format.

Basically, I'm trying to force the Othermill to behave like a ShopBot.

In EAGLE; Is there a way to bypass the schematic process, convert those DXF files into traces, accurately place drill points, and export the finished design as a .brd or .gbr?

Comment: Eagle is probably not the best tool for going from a DXF to milling toolpaths, rather you may want to look at more ordinary CAM software, or ask the machine manufacturers for a recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `import-dxf` ULP on Github which will allow you to import the DXF file into Eagle as copper. You can then export Gerber files and Excellon drill files.

But it may require additional work adding the drill holes. If the pads are circles in the DXF you will get circles in Eagle so you can find the exact centre and place pads there. Depending on the spacing of the holes this could be sped up with copy and paste if they are on a standard grid (IC sockets are 0.1" pitch).

There are probably better options depending on what you milling machine software uses. But in direct answer to your question, yes you can import the DXF and generate gerbers with a little work.